# Showing a message one time to current user

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the user login in the site I want to show message dialog saying that we have added new features to the website. I want to show this only one time, the user has just to press OK to close the dialog.

For this I added a field in the model of the user :

```
public bool hasSeenTheMessage {get;set;}
```

Can you please guide me how to do this ? I have a method like this :

```
 if (!CurrentUser.hasSeenTheMessage)
                {
                    userservice.SetUserhasSeenTheMessage(CurrentUser.Id);

                    CurrentUser.hasSeenTheMessage = true;

                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CS2-User"] = CurrentUser;

                    return PartialView("NewTermsMessage"); 
                }
```

I am stuck at this point, I have no idea what should I do next.

A tutorial online would be welcomed aswell.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the issue?

Comment: So if the user has not seen the message I will return the partialView. What if the view from where I am calling this partial view does not use  the UserModel, but uses another model instead . How will I show the view I am calling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout page you can do something like:

```
@if (Session["CS2-User"]!=null && !(CurrentUser)Session["CS2-User"].hasSeenTheMessage)){Html.Partial("NewTermsMessage")}
```

Comment: In my scenario it did not work. But it sure does respond to the question. So I accepted it .Thank you